# Image_Augmentation along with annotations

Tags: image-augmentation

I am planning to create augmented images and I do also have an annotation file along with .jpg/.jpeg/.png file. The task is to create photos along with annotations consistent with the annotations I already have. Kindly help me in this regard.

I tried a lot of things